# Validation rule on OpportunityLineItem (opportunity product)

Tags: visualforce, formula, validation-rule, opportunity-lineitem

On a visualforce page, I am creating an opportunity and I am adding an OpportunityLineItem (opportunity product) to it.

The product2 linked to the opportunity product has a field called *Maximum_Discount_in_percent_EUR__c*, which is a percent field and specify the maximun discount possible.

When adding the opportunity product on the visualforce page, you can enter a discount in % (standard *Discount* field) or a net price (*Net_Price_Discount__c*). There is a validation rule preventing you for entering both.

The opportunity product has a validation rule checking if the discount is not superior to the authorized discount.
Here is the rule's formula:

```
AND(
NOT($User.ByPass_VR__c),
OR(
AND(
Product2.Maximum_Discount_in_percent_EUR__c <> 0,
IF(ISBLANK(Discount) || ISNULL(Discount),
(ListPrice - (Product2.Maximum_Discount_in_percent_EUR__c * ListPrice)) >= Net_Price_Discount__c,
Product2.Maximum_Discount_in_percent_EUR__c < Discount))
)
)
```

I have tested the NOT($User.ByPass_VR__c) line, and it is not giving me any problems.

When I enter a discount in the *Discount* field superior the authorized one, the validation rule worked fine and I get my error message.
But when I enter e net price in *Net_Price_Discount__c* inferior to the authorized one, then it doesn't work and I can save the opportunity product.

Is the problem in my formula or can it be somewhere else?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually find a solution to my problem.

I made a new separated validation rule. Because there is already a validation rule preventing you for entering a discount in percent and a net price, I don't need to check if the *Discount* field is blank or null.
Here is the validation rules formula:

```
AND( 
NOT($User.ByPass_VR__c), 
OR( 
AND( 
Product2.Maximum_Discount_in_percent_NOK__c <> 0, 
(PricebookEntry.UnitPrice - (Product2.Maximum_Discount_in_percent_NOK__c * PricebookEntry.UnitPrice)) > Net_Price_Discount__c)
)
)
```

A good old divide and conquer solution ;-)